# Java convert data/time between timezone is inaccurate

Tags: java, timezone

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
    System.out.println("Default Timezone: " + TimeZone.getDefault());
    String date = "08/04/2016 00:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatMoscow = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date moscowDt = simpleDateFormatMoscow.parse(date);
    System.out.println("Moscow Date: " + simpleDateFormatMoscow.format(moscowDt));
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
    System.out.println("Bangkok Date: " + simpleDateFormat.format(moscowDt));
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(moscowDt);
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
    System.out.println("Bangkok Date: " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
    System.out.println("Test Timezone");
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
    System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
```

I tried to use the code this snippet to convert date/time between Moscow and Bangkok. The result is as followed:

Default Timezone:

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Moscow",offset=14400000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=78,lastRule=null]
>
> Moscow Date: 08/04/2016 00:00:00
>
> //util date/time
>
> Bangkok Date: 08/04/2016 03:00:00
>
> //joda time
>
> Bangkok Date: 08/04/2016 03:00:00

However, when I convert date/time using https://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/java-timezone-correctionconversion-with-daylight-savings-time-settings/ or google the time is

> Moscow Date: 08/04/2016 00:00:00
>
> Bangkok Date: 08/04/2016 04:00:00

Could anyone please tell me the correct way to convert data/time using java?
And Could anyone please tell me what I did wrong and why the result is inaccurate?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java have wrong timezone offset: "offset=14400000" is 4 hours, but Moscow is UTC+3 for last year and a half.

Upgrade your java with tzupdater.

Comment: Thank you so much Mikhail Kuchma. After tzupdater, The result is as aspected. Moscow Date: 08/04/2016 00:00:00
Bangkok Date: 08/04/2016 04:00:00

Comment: It's hard to say - it depends only on your needs. As for me - I have done this only once, just for Moscow timezone.

Comment: [Time in Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia) has been changing frequently in recent years. [Boundaries have been changing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia#History_of_zone_boundaries). Daylight Saving Time [(DST) has been changing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia#Daylight_saving_time), redefined in 2011 and in 2014.

Answer (score 2):

Java is using its own timezone data which is independenct from the host operation system. It might be inaccurate if you are not using the latest version of Java cause Russia (Europe/Moscow) has [switched from daylight saving time to permanent standard time two years ago](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-abandons-permanent-summer-time.html)

Comment: Thanks so much bedrin. It is true that my java timezone is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it using your local time zone first.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  // Create a calendar object and set it time based on the local time zone
    Calendar localTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    localTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
    localTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    localTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

    int hour = localTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = localTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = localTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);


    // Print the local time
    System.out.printf("Local time  : %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);


    // Create a calendar object for representing a Bangkok time zone. Then we set
    //the time of the calendar with the value of the local time

    Calendar BangkokTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangkok"));
    BangkokTime.setTimeInMillis(localTime.getTimeInMillis());
    hour = BangkokTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minute = BangkokTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    second = BangkokTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);


    // Print the local time in Bangkok time zone
    System.out.printf("Bangkok time: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);


    //Then do the same for the Moscow time zone
    Calendar MoscowTime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));
    MoscowTime.setTimeInMillis(localTime.getTimeInMillis());
    hour = MoscowTime.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minute = MoscowTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    second = MoscowTime.get(Calendar.SECOND);


    // Print the local time in Moscow time zone
    System.out.printf("Moscow time: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute, second);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer Kyle Longrich. After I have done tzupdater, the result is as expected.